# Is FireBase App indexing possible in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-app-indexing

Is there any way to implement firebase app indexing in flutter app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Indexing is currently not part of the [Firebase products that is wrapped in Flutter](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages), nor are there currently [plans](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2582) to wrap it.

If you want to use App Indexing in Flutter, you'll have to provide a wrapping library yourself.